# $\binom{n^2}{n}$ complexity (as a function of $n$)

Tags: notation, binomial-coefficients

What is the $O(\cdot)$ complexity of $\binom{n^2}{n}$?

Comment: What have you done? Do you know the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) ?

Comment: Do you mean the complexity of computing it, or do you just want $\binom{n^2}{n}=O(\cdot)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stirling's approximation is irrelevant to the calculation of computational complexity of ${n^2 \choose n}$.  Recall that in this context the [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) describes the asymptotic number of fundamental operations such as multiplications and divisions needed to compute the answer as the problem grows larger.  Of course, finding the computational complexity of an *approximation* is not the same as finding the computational complexity of the *true solution*. (After all, there are many polynomial approximations to NP-compete problems such as the Traveling Salesman Problem.)

Note the OP is asking about the computational complexity, not the value of the function.  For instance, given a constant $a$, we have $f(x)=ax$ grows linearly with $x$ but its computational complexity is ${\cal O}(1)$ due to a single multiplication, regardless of the size of $x$.  For schoolbook multiplication of two $n \times n$ matrices, the computational complexity is ${\cal O}(n^3)$, for instance.  (There are actually more efficient methods.)

For the stated problem we have:

$${n^2 \choose n}={(n^2)(n^2-1)(n^2-2)\cdots (n^2-n)(n^2-n-1)\cdots (1) \over (n)(n-1)\cdots (1) (n^2-n)(n^2-n-1) \cdots (1)}$$

$$={(n^2)(n^2-1)\cdots (n^2-n+1) \over (n)(n-1)\cdots (1)}$$

There are $n+1$ multiplications in the numerator and $n$ in the denominator and a single division.  The computational complexity is thus ${\cal O}(2n)$.

Here is a graph of the compute time (a rough but useful estimate of the time complexity) for a non-optimized version of this problem, where the abscissa is the $n$ and the ordinate is time.  Notice this is nearly linear.  Since this implementation used full combinations, rather than the simplifications above, the curve will be slightly worse than linear... just as we find.

[image]

Comment: Who is talking about  **computational**  complexity? The OP does not have answered the corresponding question. From the original revision it seems unlikely. And IMO your
answer is kind of trivial, and I would prefer the bit-complexity.

Comment: @gammatester:  The OP is talking about computational complexity, not the *order of an expansion* (which doesn't reference "complexity" at all).  For instance, $\sin x = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! + {\cal O}(x^7)$, but this has nothing to do with "complexity."  Bit complexity refers to the number of sub operations (differing between $5 \cdot 7$ and $2 \cdot 3$, for example) and the OP gives no hint that level of complexity is relevant.

Comment: You interpret this from the graphics showing $O{n^2 \choose n}?$ There is **no mentioning** of complexity at all!

Comment: @gammatester:  What are you talking about??!  The poser asks:  "What is the ${\cal O}(⋅)$ **complexity** of ${n^2 \choose n}$?"  Not "What is ${\cal O}{n^2 \choose n}$?"  You said "no mentioning of complexity at all"???!!!  And what "graphics" are you talking about?  I see none.

Comment: No! She/he does not, see the **original revision** https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2428219/revisions

Comment: I'm answering the question as it stands... which is the only version I saw and what we're all supposed to do anyway, since it contains revisions from the OP.  (By the way:  What did "bit complexity" have to do with *anything*?)

Answer (score 1):

By using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) 
$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\,\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^n},$$ we obtain
$$\binom{n^2}{n}=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)\cdot (n^2-n+1) }{n!}\sim \frac{C n^{2n}}{n!}\sim C' n^{n-1/2}e^n$$
where $C$ and $C'$ are positive constants.

Comment: Actually, finding the computational complexity of an *approximation* is not the same as finding the computational complexity of the true solution.  (After all, there are many polynomial approximations to NP-compete problems such as the Traveling Salesman Problem.)  Note the OP is asking about the computational complexity, not the *value* of the function.  For instance, given a constant $a$, we have $f(x) = a x$ grows linearly with $x$ but its computational complexity is ${\cal O}(1)$ due to a single multiplication, regardless of the size of $x$.

Comment: @David G. Stork So for example, what is  the computational complexity of $n!$. Is it ${\cal O}(n)$?

Comment: Yes.  See my solution, below.

Comment: @David G. Stork OK. +1 for your answer. Now OP has an answer for both possible interpretation of his/her question.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use Stirling's approximation

$$ n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n$$

and substitute in the definition $C(n^2, n)$.